# Relation between weak topology and topology of weak convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#Weak_convergence), the weak topology on a topological vector space $X$ is the initial topology with respect to its continuous dual $X^*$. In other words, it is the coarsest topology (the topology with the fewest open sets) such that each element of $X^*$ is a continuous function.

> a net $(x_λ)$ in $X$ converges in the weak topology to the element $x$ of $X$ if and only if $φ(x_λ)$ converges to $φ(x)$ in $\mathbb R$ or $C$ for all $φ$ in $X^*$.

If I am correct, a net $(x_λ)$ in $X$ is said to converge weakly to $x$, if $φ(x_λ)$ converges to $φ(x)$ in $\mathbb R$ or $C$ for all $φ$ in $X^*$. Weak convergence therefore is a pointwise convergence, and has the topology of pointwise convergence on $X$ viewed as a set of linear functionals on $X^*$.

Does the quote above equivalently mean that the weak topology on $X$ is the same as the topology of pointwise convergence for weak convergence?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "topology of pointwise convergence for weak convergence." You are correct in saying the weak topology on $X$ is the same as the topology of pointwise convergence, where $X$ is viewed as a space of functions with domain $X^*$ and codomain equal to the field of the vector space $X$.